# How can i override previous styling in a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming, clearfix

Ok, this is the styling I want to be used

```
 .suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility span {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      padding-left: 10px;

    }
```

The usual of mentioning the element here doesn't seem to work, any ideas? I can specify more if need be. I am new and not great at specifying my problem!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use important like

```
.suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility span {
      display: inline-block !important;
      float: left !important;
      padding-left: 10px !important;

    }
```

Comment: I think it's is an bad idea. Try to avoid `!important` as much as you can. With the correct CSS selector you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Place your style after the theme stylesheet. It will override the theme styling. Better still, you can replace the suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility class span styling in the styles.css file. If you opt for the latter, changes will be lost when updating the theme. You can avoid this by building a child theme to the theme you are currently using.

Comment: I am little confused what exactly your first method is. I have created a child theme and that is what I am editing and it is still causing me issues.

Comment: On the header.php file, the theme's styles have been linked there. You simply place your styling below those links. If you're using a child theme, replace the rules in .suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility span {} block with the rules you want to top be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important tag in each, ex:

```
.someclass {
 width: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work...  
`.suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility span {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: left !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;

}`

Comment: @DavidJamesMitten those properties that you want to override are in the style attribute of your span? I mean, you have <span class="XXX" style="xxxx" /> style attr will override any css.

Comment: I'm not sure as it is hard to locate them, I am editing someone else's code.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any specific attributes for the span tag. I have had some progression by adding a predesigned `clear: both;` that at least shows I can effect it.

Comment: @DavidJamesMitten check using chrome dev console (F12 on windows) and check if that span have some style attribute. Can you put more info about your file access, if you can edit php files of your theme, you can override any css and style attributes with JS and jQuery, using this code on header php file: <script>$(document).ready(function() {
 var class = $('.suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility');
        class.find('span').attr('style','display: inline-block;float: left;padding-left: 10px;');
 });</script>